# How do I find how many numbers are prime(taking absolute value of negatives) in a list? When i use count it returns zero

Tags: prime-numbers, mathematica-online

```
    f =  9x^2 - 78x-10000
    list1 = PrimeQ[Abs[f /. x -> {Range[1, 20]}]]
    Count[list1,True]
```

This is my code. Im trying to find how many prime numbers there are between the range 1-20. If a number is negative i have to take the absolute value of it.

I need to know how many numbers are prime. I tried using count(i want to see how many times true shows up) but it keeps returning 0
thank you

Comment: Your code can be simplify. `f = 9 x^2 - 78 x - 10000; list1 = 
 PrimeQ[Abs[f /. x -> Range[1, 20]]]; Count[list1, True]`

Comment: how can i add simplify? thank you

Comment: thank you i just tried it it works!

Comment: `Abs` is not need.

Comment: My prof said to take the absolute value of the negative numbers, what else can i use besides abs, thank you

Comment: Sorry, I means that the code can be wrote as `f = 9 x^2 - 78 x - 10000; list1 = 
 PrimeQ[f /. x -> Range[20]]; Count[list1, True]`

Comment: Your problem was due to the list brackets in the replacement rule. With the brackets `Count` is operating on a matrix rather than a vector. **Either** remove the brackets (i.e., `x -> Range[1, 20]`) **or** add a level specification to `Count` (i.e., `Count[list1, True, {2}]`)

Comment: thank you for helping me understand, i was wondering what does {2} stand for in Count[list1, True, {2}]. also what is level specification? thanks again

Comment: See `Levels in Expressions` (tutorial/Expressions#31184) in the tutorial (Tech Note) [`Expressions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Expressions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a pity not to see the values of the function that are prime as well as how many there are. We can avoid suppressing them while still getting the answer we want:

```
f = 9 x^2 - 78 x - 10000
primes = Select[f /.x -> Range[1, 20], PrimeQ]
Length[primes]
```

`PrimeQ` automatically treats negative primes as prime, which is why you don't need `Abs`.